# Método getText del control EditText

Tags: android

Hola tengo en el xml de un Control de tipo EditText:

```
android:hint="nombre por defecto"
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando invoco el método

```
txtSaludar.getText().toString()
```

No coge el valor "nombre por defecto", pero si cambio ese nombre por defecto por otro cualquiera entonces sí. La duda es... qué hacer, qué método ejecutar para que pille ese nombre por defecto.

Gracias anticipadas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor de `hint` existe el método `getHint()` el cual Android define del modo siguiente en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHint()):

> Returns the hint that is displayed when the text of the TextView is
>   empty.
>
> Retorna el `hint` que es desplegado **cuando el texto del textView
>   está vacío**.

Ejemplo:

```
String myTxtHint = new String ();
myTxtHint=myTxtView.getHint().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Puedes llamar al metodo `txtSaludar.getHint();`
2. Puedes cambiar hint por text en tu xml
3. Puedes validar si esta vacio y definir el valor por defecto desde el código

```
static final String default = "Nombre por defecto";
//tambien puedes llamar un string desde R.strings...
String texto = txtSaludar.getText().toString(); 
//podrías validar si esta vacio
if(texto.isEmpty()||texto!=null) { 
   //aqui cuando no escribieron nada 
   texto = default;
} else { 
   //aqui cuando si escribieron algo
}
```

Saludos!